# How to Authenticate to use Google Cloud Vision API

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I am currently trying to use Google Cloud Vision API on C#.

After downloading JSON file for google cloud authentication, I have set the system environment variable as the path of the JSON file and compiled my code. It was all good.

However, when I created DLL with the source it seems like the DLL could not get the Google Application Credentials value from the system environment variable.

So that I studied some of the Google Credential Authentication documents to put a code at the very first line of C# code to deliver my JSON file path to recognize my vision api calls.

However, **the code is not working to properly authenticating my JSON file to call Google Vision API.**

Please enlighten me with your knowledge! Thanks.

Here is my code.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using Google.Cloud.Vision.V1;
using Image = Google.Cloud.Vision.V1.Image;
using Grpc.Core;
using Grpc.Auth;


namespace dotNetFramework461_Console
{
    class Program
    {
        public string GVA_API()
        {
            string jsonPath = "D:\\blablablah\\abcdefghijk.json";
            string imgPath = "C:\\Users\\blablablah\\image.jpg";

            var stream = new FileStream(jsonPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            var credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream).CreateScoped(ImageAnnotatorClient.DefaultScopes);
            var channel = new Grpc.Core.Channel(ImageAnnotatorClient.DefaultEndpoint.ToString(), credential.ToChannelCredentials());
            var client = ImageAnnotatorClient.Create(channel);
            var image = Image.FromFile(imgPath);

            TextAnnotation text = client.DetectDocumentText(image);
            return text.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn about [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's great that we've got a fairly complete example (although `GoogleCredential.FromFile` is simpler) - but we don't know what the result is. When you say "the code is not working to properly authenticating my JSON file" what *exactly* do you mean? Are you seeing an exception? Assuming you have, please post the complete exception details - type, message and stack trace - in your question.